# How do I implement addMatchers in Mocha?

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, mocha.js, chai

I'm working through the Testing with CoffeScript book that teaches BDD using Jasmine, but I'm using Mocha/Chai instead, and came across this piece of code:

```
beforeEach -> 
  @addMatchers  
    toBeDiscounted: (orig,discount) ->  
      actual = @actual  
      @message = -> "Expected #{actual} to be #{discount}% of #{orig}"  
      actual is (orig * (1-(discount/100)))
```

and then in the test:

```
it "should persist the discount", ->  
  expect(test.basket.applyDiscount(10)).toBeDiscounted(50, 10)
```

How do i do this in Mocha/Chai?

Comment: See this article http://chaijs.com/guide/helpers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasmine matchers are equivalent to *Chai Helpers* in Mocha/Chai land.
You will need to update your spec helper to include a [Custom Chai Helper](http://chaijs.com/guide/helpers/). Then, you need to write the Chai Helper itself; making it extend Chai to add a `discounted` function.

*spec/spec-helper.js*

```
var chai = require('chai');

var chaiDiscounted = require('./helpers/discounted.js')
chai.use(chaiDiscounted);
```

*spec/helpers/discounted.js*

```
function discount(x, discount) {
  return x * (1 - (discount / 100));
}

module.exports = function(chai) {
  var Assertion = chai.Assertion;

  Assertion.addMethod('discounted', function (y, p) {
    var obj = this._obj;
    new Assertion(obj).to.be.a('number');
    this.assert(
        obj === discount(y, p)
      , "expected #{this} to be " + y + "% of " + p
      , "expected #{this} to not be " + y + "% of " + p
    );
  });
}
```

You should then be able to do:

```
expect(foo).to.be.discounted(50, 10)
```

*Sorry I haven't tested this. Also, I apologize that this is in Javascript (not Coffeescript) ... but hopefully it will help point you in the right direction.*